# Lumen SQLSTATE error when inserting symbol into database when utf8mb4

Tags: php, mysql, lumen

I am running Lumen 5.8 and I have a table and database that I want to add games to, I'm using this for my migration:

```
    Schema::create('games', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('slug');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->timestamps();
        
        $table->charset = 'utf8mb4';
        $table->collation = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';
    });
```

As you can see I set the charset and collation.

Also I added to `.env`:

```
DB_CHARSET=utf8mb4
DB_COLLATION=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

[image]

SO when I try and add a game like `Pokémon`

```
$game = new Game();
$game->slug = "pokemon-red"
$game->name = "Pokémon Red"
$game->save();
```

I get

```
   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xE3\xA9mon-...' for column 'slug' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `games` (`slug`, `name`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (pokmon-white-version-2, Pokémon White Version 2, 2019-04-08 05:28:57, 2019-04-08 05:28:57))
```

I'm not sure why I'm still getting the error. I am able to insert it directly into a field in PHPMyAdmin without an issue so I assume it has something to do with Lumen specifically.

For reference, I found this first and that's why everything is set to utf8mb4:

[Cannot insert chinese in mysql database through utf8 encoding ( Warning 1336 incorrect string value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31648933/cannot-insert-chinese-in-mysql-database-through-utf8-encoding-warning-1336-inc)

I specifically made sure to go in and insert a record in PHPMyAdmin and it worked, which leads me to believe this is a Lumen configuration issue.

Comment: Have you tried using `utf8_encode()` for your `$game->name`?

Comment: I have not I'll go try this! `$game->name = utf8_encode("Pokémon Red");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments I determined that it was in fact that the name was not already encoded like I thought it was. so adding

```
$game->name = utf8_encode("Pokémon Red");
```

Fixed the issue!